# "К вам на помощь" или "вам на помощь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Писала вчера фразу и вдруг задумалась: "Я уже спешу (к) вам на помощь" — как правильно сказать? Нужен ли тут предлог К?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если чисто стилистически подходить, то оба варианта возможны. Есть некоторые различия в смысле.
Если во главе угла - физическое перемещение, что уже само по себе может быть истолковано как помощь, - то "к вам". Если проблема не в перемещении, а помощь можно оказать и дистанционно, то "вам". 
Смотрите контекст. Хотя, вернее всего, будет что-то среднее, выбирайте то, что звучит для Вас лучше.
//------
Добавлю. В языке военных обычно "Вам в помощь". Долго вспоминал, увы...